# Convert single row with comma seperator into multiple Column

Tags: sql-server, string, csv, join, sql-server-2012

If I issue

```
SELECT ID FROM TestAhmet
```

I get this result:

```
1,2,3,4,5
```

but what I really need is multiple column with all the values separated by comma, like this:

```
1
3
5
2
4
```

How do I do this?

Comment: If possible I would recommend changing the Table to not store comma separated values in the first place.  Instead have those values in a separate table with a many-to-one relationship to the TestAhmet table.

Comment: Do you want to achieve that on server side or client side?

Comment: Hi Guru, Server side.

Comment: @Subash don't store such values in the first place. It's a bug. In all SQL Server versions in mainstream support (2016+) you can use `STRING_SPLIT`. You'll find a *lot* of similar SO questions too. The XML Path technique is probably the fastest

Comment: The best option for any version would be to split the data on the server and store it in a separate table, on multiple rows, just like any other data. Another option would be to store the data as XML and use XML methods for querying.

Comment: Hi Guru, Thnaks for your suggestion:-)

Comment: @Subash does the table really contain `1,2,3,4,5` as a single ID value? In that case you have a far more serious problem and won't be able to query your data. Was there a display problem perhaps, that made multiple values appear in a single row instead of multiple rows perhaps?

Comment: Hi Guru,
Thats not a id value, i have posted just for eg.

Comment: @Guru actually you assume this as logic not assume this as table structure.

Comment: You want the output as multiple rows or columns?

Comment: I have added an answer that works on SQL Server 2012, but do note the the data should be stored in a separate table, your `ID` column is not normalized

Answer (score 3):

If you are running SQL Server 2016 or later, you can use [table-valued function `string_split()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15):

```
select value
from TestAhmet t
cross apply string_split(t.id, ',')
```

Comment: Hi GMB,
Thanks for your update, bad luck i am using sql 2012. Please give solution for that version.

Comment: @Subash SO is not a free code-writing service. Splitting strings has been (and likely will continue to be) a constant topic; a little searching will find many examples of code that will accomplish this for any version of sql server.

Comment: @Subash I have edited your question to add sql 2012 tag, so it gets more accurate answers

Comment: @Subash In 2012 you can use a replace to form XML nodes and the XML related functions

Answer (score 0):

You can make this query as a function and use it across procs.

```
DECLARE @list varchar(MAX)= '1,2,3,4,5',
        @pos        int,
        @nextpos    int,
        @valuelen   int
DECLARE  @tbl TABLE (number int  NULL)

   SELECT @pos = 0, @nextpos = 1

   WHILE @nextpos > 0
   BEGIN
      SELECT @nextpos = charindex(',', @list, @pos + 1)
      SELECT @valuelen = CASE WHEN @nextpos > 0
                              THEN @nextpos
                              ELSE len(@list) + 1
                         END - @pos - 1
      INSERT @tbl (number)
         VALUES (convert(int, substring(@list, @pos + 1, @valuelen)))
      SELECT @pos = @nextpos
   END

   SELECT * FROM @tbl
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use XML related functions that are available on SQL Server 2012

Reference: [XML nodes() function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/xml/nodes-method-xml-data-type?view=sql-server-ver15) and [XML value() function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/xml/value-method-xml-data-type?view=sql-server-ver15)

```sql
DECLARE @text_to_split nvarchar(100) = '1,10,4,6'

SELECT document.node.value('.', 'int') as id
FROM
     (SELECT CAST('<content><x>' + REPLACE(@text_to_split, ',', '</x><x>') + '</x></content>' AS XML) as content) xml_data
     CROSS APPLY xml_data.content.nodes('/content/x') as document(node)
```

The output is:

```
1
10
4
6
```

## Explanation

What we do is translate that data into a valid XML:

```
CAST('<content><x>' + REPLACE(@text_to_split, ',', '</x><x>') + '</x></content>' AS XML) as content
```

Then we do a `CROSS APPLY` to be able to work with it as a table estructured XML data

```
CROSS APPLY xml_data.content.nodes('/content/x') as document(node)
```

And finally we extract the content of the XML nodes and cast it as integers

```
SELECT document.node.value('.', 'int') as id
```